# Solving $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z^2+1)} \ dz$ by the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

> I am tring to find $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z^2+1)} \ dz,$$ where $\Gamma$ is the circle $|z|=2$.

My attempt:

Let $f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z^2+1)}.$ Now, $f$ has singularities at $z=0,\pm i$.

$z=0$ is a pole of order $2$ and the residue is:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{(z^2+1)}\right)=\frac{-z^2\sin(z)-\sin(z)-2z\cos(z)}{(z+1)^2}=0.$$

$z=i$ is a simple pole and has residue:
$$\lim_{z\to i} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z+i)}=\frac{\cos(i)}{-2i}=\frac{\cosh(1)}{-2i}.$$

$z=-i$ is a simple pole and similar to above, has residue $\frac{\cosh(1)}{2i}.$

Now by the Residue theorem (all singularities lie inside $\Gamma$), $$\int_\Gamma f(z) \ dz=2\pi i\left(0-\frac{\cosh(1)}{2i}+\frac{\cosh(1)}{2i}\right)=0.$$

Is this a correct use of the Residue theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Just to note, if your contour is more complicated you must factor in the winding number for each pole as well. Here they are all trivially 1.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't quite understand what you mean by "winding number for each pole". Are you able to give an example?

Comment: This should explain: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourWindingNumber.html

Comment: Interesting. In the case that my contour above is traversed in the clockwise direction, would $$\int_{\Gamma }f(z) \ dz=-2\pi i(\text{Res}(f,z_i)) \ \ i=1,2,3$$

Comment: you can traverse it either way, just be consistent and it will work out. Of course in this case, $0=-0$ so it won't affect the final result, but you do need to be cautious in general.